# SQLite 'WHERE !=' causing empty result

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a piece of working code for a Python/SQLite script:

```
 cur.execute('SELECT id, title, thm ' +
             'FROM content ' +
             'ORDER BY id ' +
             'DESC LIMIT 5')
```

And I want to perform the same operation but not counting entries that have the 'disabled' column set to 'DISABLED', and came up with the following code:

```
 cur.execute('SELECT id, title, thm ' +
             'FROM content ' +
             'WHERE disabled != ? ' +
             'ORDER BY id ' +
             'DESC LIMIT 5',
             ("DISABLED",))
```

However instead of throwing an error (so I assume the syntax is fine) or providing the correct output, the return value of the statement is simply an empty list.

The test database I'm working from has 8 entries - 2 with 'disabled' set to 'DISABLED' and the remaining 6 set to NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(NULL) disabled != ?` is never true.

Comment: as far as i know for not equal to you should use <>

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks, setting the NULL values to something solved the issue.

Comment: You could have used `WHERE (disabled != ?) OR (disabled IS NULL)`.